# Can hydraulics be used with a squarish piston?

Tags: hydraulics, pistons, shock

I'm designing a custom part that needs an active shock absorber and space is restricted. I most likely won't be able to use a stock absorber and was thinking, can two squarish tubes be made tight enough?

Comment: Anything can be made accurately enough with enough money.  It's much easier to make round precision parts, though, particularly bores.  Instead of asking us, ask your machine shop.

Comment: Would a square ram be more likely to jam through a rotating load?

Comment: @TimWescott I don't have a machine shop.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming reasonable pressures, it should be workable.

However, keep in mind that the pressures will be higher at the corners and you'll run a higher risk of leakage / bursting.  Cylindrical tubes distribute the pressure evenly across the bearing surface and don't have that issue.

You'll also potentially have difficulty with fabricating a gasket to seal the space between the square tubes.

Given the minimal difference in surface area between a cylindrical and square tube, and the ready prevalence of cylindrical tubes, it does beg the question as to why you feel a square tube is the more appropriate design choice.

Comment: The thinking of square tube came from space constraints (I may end up making a custom integrated part instead of stock tubes) and from the wish it would prevent axial rotation. However, thinking about this more I think the mere shape is not enough to remove rotation, since the two sides of the cylinder won't actually meet due to tightenings). I'll look at stock cylinders and/or make mine round.

Comment: @ GlenH7: I’m very curious why you are mentioning that the pressure will be higher in the corners. I thought that in a hydraulic chamber the pressure is in every point the same. I rather think you mean the tension in the material of the piston could be higher. Perhaps you can clarify. Thanks.